# file.canWrite() says "true" but I can't write on removable storage (kit kat)

Tags: android, file-io, storage, sd-card

I recieve a intent from camera with a photo taken in this path:
/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/photoCaptured.jpg

And I want to resize (already does) of the image and overwrite in the same path...
I can do it on 2.3, 4.1 and 4.3, but... not in 4.4

so... maybe the problem is the permission on this folder, so I check with this...

```
if( myFile.canWrite() ){
    Log.e("myMethodToSave", "you have permission: " + myFile);
} else {
    Log.e("myMethodToSave", "forget it!: " + myFile);
}
```

...and I have permission to write but 4.4, says Permission Denied
Why?
How can I resolve this?

**EDITED**

```
salida = new FileOutputStream(myFile);  //error only on kit kat
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, salida);
```

Comment: What code gives the "Permission Denied" error?

Comment: I already added the code :)

Comment: did you add a permission to your mainfest?

Comment: yes... <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />