# Checking permission of write to external storage in Android application

Tags: android, android-external-storage, file-properties

Normal way to do that is checking whether the `manifest` uses `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission:

```
String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
int res = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

My question is in about using `canWrite()` method.Docs say:

> public boolean canWrite ()
>    Added in API level 1
>   Indicates whether the
>   current context is allowed to write to this file.

So we can use this method to check permission like this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite();
```

This way seems to be simpler than first way and also does not need to use `Context`.Also we can use same to check `read permission`.But is this a good way to check those?Also is it a good way to check if manifest uses read/write permissions?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469893/file-canwrite-says-true-but-i-cant-write-on-removable-storage-kit-kat. No you cannot use `canWrite` instead of checking the `manifest`.

Comment: @MartinKonecny So why does doc say `Indicates whether the current context is allowed to write to this file.`?What is difference between permit of `canWrite()` and permit that is earned by permission in manifest?

Comment: because the manifest permission allows you write on SD card but canWrite() means you are allowed to write in this particular file. Having access to a city does not necessarily mean that you have access to every building. :)

Comment: @MartinKonecny Thank you for your attention.It seems that  File.canRead()/canWrite()/canExecute() ignore access control lists (ACLs).But why we can not use AccessController to check access permissions as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30521951/1043882 ?