# How to use AccessController in android?

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-external-storage

In an Android application (API level 10),I do not use below permission in `manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So application would not write on root of external storage.But when I try to check `read/write` permission via `AccessController` by this code:

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
String actions = "read,write";
try {
    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(path, actions));
    Log.d("Tag", "You have read/write permition to use : " + path);
} catch (AccessControlException e) {
    Log.d("Tag", "You have not read/write permition to use : " + path);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d("Tag", "You have not read/write permition to use : " + path);
}
```

Result will be:

> You have read/write permition to use : /storage/sdcard0

So why `AccessController.checkPermission` does not throw exception on root of External Storage when application has no permission to write on it?